# Midory browser: where are the bookmarks?

Tags: linux, gui, browser, bookmarks

[image]

Midori browser 9.0 has a button to save bookmarks but I cannot find a way to list them after they are saved.

I have found [old posts](https://answers.launchpad.net/midori/+question/198531) on this problem with solutions related to "menubar" or "sidebar" that are not present on later versions.

Comment: I installed Midori v9.0-1.3 on openSUSE Tumbleweed. I'm guessing bookmarks go into the speed dial. There doesn't seem to be a bookmark toolbar or a GUI to manage bookmarks other than the icon you circled, AFAICT. Maybe you can remove them from the speed dial?

Comment: @DKBose - the speed dial contains recent visited linked whether bookmarked or not. The more recent take precedent and there's no way of telling which one is bookmarked.

Comment: Looking into this a bit more: `~/.config/midori` has `bookmarks.db`, `bookmarks.db-shm`, and `bookmarks.db-wal`. The modification time of the last two files reflect bookmarks added. I still can't figure out how to access the bookmarks via a GUI. I think midori is a work-in-progress. If you seriously want to use bookmarks in Midori, you may want a file an issue at https://github.com/midori-browser/core/issues.

Comment: Odd response here: https://github.com/midori-browser/core/issues/355

Comment: @DKBose - `midori is a work-in-progress` - As the full UI is so limited I find it more interesting fully bare: with `midori -a` it can run as web app. As it is a bit lighter than others, I'll keep it for that purpose (whatsapp etc).

Answer (score 2):

Control + D or Control + B, shows a list of bookmarks, same as in Speedial, under the address bar. There are X buttons at the end of each, to click to remove them. Only a few remove at a time, as you X out, then back into Speedial. Multiple cycles like this may be needed  to remove all bookmarks/history.